# PHP having syntax problems with quotations wrapped around a variable in PHP embedded in HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

This appears right to me but it is incorrect (code hint coloring around '{$row["type"]}' is wrong wrong -- from the color it is in my IDE it's been considering a string, and it's throwing an error when i run it in the browser). I've spent hours trying to figure this out on my own to no avail.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
echo "<select selected = '{$row["type"]}'  name='expense[" . $id . "][type]' >" .       $type_options . "</select>";
```

Comment: echo "Some String $type_options Additional String";

Comment: You can't have double quote inside double quote.

Comment: The code coloring isn't "wrong wrong", it's showing you exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently have a problem with unescaped double quotes terminating your string. My suggestion would be to use the more standard double-quotes for your HTML element properties, and use single quotes to delineate your strings, with variable concatenated. Liek this:

```
echo '<select selected = "' . {$row["type"]} . '" name="expense[' . $id . '][type]">' . $type_options . '</select>';
```

or for even better readability, use printf

```
$format = '<select selected = "%s" name="expense[%d][type]">%s</select>';
printf($format, $row['type'], $id, $type_options);
```

Answer (score 2):

When using arrays in strings, you can't use quotes. Just skip them.

```
echo "<select selected = '{$row[type]}'  name='expense[" . $id . "][type]' >" .       $type_options . "</select>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your quotes arren't right.

```
echo '<select selected ="'.$row["type"].'"  name="expense['.$id.'][type]">'.$type_options.'</select>';
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$type_options = "options";

echo $type_options;
```

Have you not tried this?

Answer (score -2):

Your code wont work because you have an empty string before you echo your variable.

```
echo "#EMPTY STRING HERE!" . $type_options . "#EMPTY STRING HERE!";
```

Why are you doing that?

Use this

```
echo $type_options;
```

Or even this if you want content in your string

```
echo "Content" . $type_options . "Content";
```

Comment: Explain better what you mean by `empty string` in his code. Maybe it'll help to understand you answer.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I asked! :D You wrote `wont work because you have an empty string before you echo your variable`, so show where is that `empty string`.

Comment: You have this echo "#EMPTY STRING HERE!" . $type_options . "#EMPTY STRING HERE!";

Answer (score -2):

```
echo "This works: {$row['type']}";
```